# Axis webcam http upload to php

Tags: php, http, webcam

Hi all i'm working on an axis p1343.
I tested the ftp upload succesfully.

Now i need to work with http upload to handle images seen that i do not need to keep ol images. So i'm writing a php script to hande the image buffer from that web cam.

After some work i realized that the cam was not sending anything.
So i created e really basic script to just test the jpg stream.

I receive a request with no data inside.

Does anyone know how that camera send the stream in the HU (Httpp Upload) mode ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED!**

**Solution**
to download data sent from the cam just use file_get_contents("php://input") so u can access the data stream a retrieve the data that cam sends as an attachment to the request.

This happens because the axis webcam use to send file as an attachment to the request simulating a "download link" request in a browser.

So to catch up those damn bits u have to read the php://input stream .... 
It took some time time to figure out this workaround ... hope this will help you.

Comment: A simple example would have very very useful. For those trying to solve this same issue. If you get time, that would be fab. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
file_put_contents('image.jpg', file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>
```